# obtaining Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. with sudo or root

Tags: java, linux, x11, sudo, centos8

I was testing my application on Linux.
The Java version is

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_251
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ java -version
}java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

Checking `DISPLAY` variable

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ printenv | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ 

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo printenv | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ 

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo -Hiu root env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo -Hiu joseluisbz env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

Here the code:

```
  private static final String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

  public static Boolean isMacOS() {
    return (OS.contains("mac") || OS.contains("darwin"));
  }

  public static Boolean isLinux() {
    return (OS.contains("nix") || OS.contains("nux") || OS.contains("aix"));
  }

  public static Boolean isWindows() {
    return (OS.contains("windows"));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("");
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    String display = System.getenv("DISPLAY");
    System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"os.name\"):" + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    System.out.println("System.getenv(\"DISPLAY\"):" + System.getenv("DISPLAY"));
    
    Boolean headless = ("Linux".equals(osName) ||
                             "SunOS".equals(osName) ||
                             "FreeBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "NetBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "OpenBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "AIX".equals(osName)) &&
                             (display == null || display.trim().isEmpty());
    System.out.println("headless:" + headless);
    System.out.println("");
    
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lafInfo : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
      System.out.println("lafInfo.getName():" + lafInfo.getName()
          + "\tinfo.getClassName():" + lafInfo.getClassName());
    }
    System.out.println("LookAndFeelInfo printed all\n");

    try {

//      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
//      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
//      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");

//      javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");
//      javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
//      javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
      if (isMacOS()) {
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.brushMetalLook", "true");
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.name", "FlexibleFileFinder");
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.EnableQ2DX", "true");
      }

      System.out.println("OS:" + OS);
      if (isMacOS()) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel");
      } else if (isLinux()) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
      } else if (isWindows()) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
      } else {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
      }
      System.out.println("UIManager.getLookAndFeel():" + UIManager.getLookAndFeel() + "\n");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
        | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        RecursiveFolderAndFiles recursiveFolderAndFiles = new RecursiveFolderAndFiles();
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu(recursiveFolderAndFiles);
        MethodGUI.enableOSXFullscreen(recursiveFolderAndFiles);
        MethodGUI.requestToggleFullScreen(recursiveFolderAndFiles);
        recursiveFolderAndFiles.setJMenuBar(mainMenu.getMainMenuBar());
        recursiveFolderAndFiles.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I was running my Java app in CentOS 8.

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"

System.getProperty("os.name"):Linux
System.getenv("DISPLAY")::0
headless:false

lafInfo.getName():Metal info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():Nimbus    info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():CDE/Motif info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():GTK+  info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
LookAndFeelInfo printed all

OS:linux
UIManager.getLookAndFeel():[GTK look and feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel]
```

Running with `sudo`

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"

System.getProperty("os.name"):Linux
System.getenv("DISPLAY")::0
headless:false

No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:132)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2031)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1158)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:431)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1577)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:539)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1349)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels(UIManager.java:419)
    at org.bz.filefinder.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:56)
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

The `line 56` is

```
for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lafInfo : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
```

Trying again with `sudo` and `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"

System.getProperty("os.name"):Linux
System.getenv("DISPLAY")::0
headless:false

lafInfo.getName():Metal info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():Nimbus    info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():CDE/Motif info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():GTK+  info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
LookAndFeelInfo printed all

OS:linux
Jul 04, 2020 5:08:17 PM org.bz.filefinder.MainClass main
SEVERE: null
javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException: [GTK look and feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel] not supported on this platform
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:526)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:583)
    at org.bz.filefinder.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:82)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at org.bz.filefinder.RecursiveFolderAndFiles.<init>(RecursiveFolderAndFiles.java:43)
    at org.bz.filefinder.MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:97)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

The `line 82` is

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
```

I was testing with

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
```

and they failed as well.!

**Why works for non `root` or `sudo` user, but it fails with `sudo` or `root`?**

NOTE:

code of `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment`

```
static void checkHeadless() throws HeadlessException {
    if (isHeadless()) { //LINE 203!!!
        throw new HeadlessException();
    }
}


public static boolean isHeadless() {
    return getHeadlessProperty();
}


private static boolean getHeadlessProperty() {
    if (headless == null) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
            String nm = System.getProperty("java.awt.headless");

            if (nm == null) {
                /* No need to ask for DISPLAY when run in a browser */
                if (System.getProperty("javaplugin.version") != null) {
                    headless = defaultHeadless = Boolean.FALSE;
                } else {
                    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
                    if (osName.contains("OS X") && "sun.awt.HToolkit".equals(
                            System.getProperty("awt.toolkit")))
                    {
                        headless = defaultHeadless = Boolean.TRUE;
                    } else {
                        final String display = System.getenv("DISPLAY");
                        headless = defaultHeadless =
                            ("Linux".equals(osName) ||
                             "SunOS".equals(osName) ||
                             "FreeBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "NetBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "OpenBSD".equals(osName) ||
                             "AIX".equals(osName)) &&
                             (display == null || display.trim().isEmpty());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                headless = Boolean.valueOf(nm);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
    return headless;
}
```

**NOTE 1**:

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo xterm
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
sudo: xterm: command not found
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ xterm
bash: xterm: command not found...
Install package 'xterm' to provide command 'xterm'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Loading list of packages.... 
The following packages have to be installed:
 xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-19.el8.noarch  misc bitmap fonts for the X Window System
 xterm-331-1.el8.x86_64 Terminal emulator for the X Window System
 xterm-resize-331-1.el8.x86_64  Set environment and terminal settings to current window size
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Waiting for authentication... 
 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Downloading packages... 
 * Requesting data... 
 * Testing changes... 
 * Installing packages... 

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

**NOTE 2**

<strike># cd /etc/X11/ && Xorg -configure
# X -config -retro /root/xorg.conf.new
# X -config -retro /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# startx</strike>

Working with `root` user.

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo startx
xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.3620 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.20.6
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  4.19.34-300.el7.x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux centos.joseluisbz 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 10 11:09:32 UTC 2020 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd1,gpt7)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 root=UUID=8e22004f-7639-4530-a2db-df80df04aa6d ro crashkernel=auto resume=UUID=8c61ca21-ec17-4aed-b695-c83c373f7ff0 rhgb quiet
Build Date: 24 April 2020  02:49:29AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.6-3.el8 
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.2.log", Time: Sat Jul  4 18:03:05 2020
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86MonBrightnessCycle
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86RotationLockToggle
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86MonBrightnessCycle
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86RotationLockToggle
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
Failed to import environment: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86MonBrightnessCycle
> Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym XF86RotationLockToggle
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

When root is logged

```
[root@centos ~]# whoami
root
[root@centos ~]# pwd
/root
[root@centos ~]# java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"

System.getProperty("os.name"):Linux
System.getenv("DISPLAY")::2
System.getProperty("java.awt.headless"):null
headless:false

lafInfo.getName():Metal info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():Nimbus    info.getClassName():javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():CDE/Motif info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel
lafInfo.getName():GTK+  info.getClassName():com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
LookAndFeelInfo printed all

OS:linux
UIManager.getLookAndFeel():[GTK look and feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel]

JFrame.class.isAssignableFrom(RecursiveFolderAndFiles.class):true
RecursiveFolderAndFiles.class.isAssignableFrom(OneSearch.class):false
RulerPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(OneSearch.class):false
RulerPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(JPanel.class):false
JPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(RulerPanel.class):true
Jul 04, 2020 6:41:10 PM org.bz.filefinder.RecursiveFolderAndFiles <init>
INFO: System.getProperty("user.dir"): /root
Jul 04, 2020 6:41:10 PM org.bz.filefinder.RecursiveFolderAndFiles <init>
INFO: System.getProperty("user.home"): /root
```

**NOTE 3**

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo xterm
No protocol specified
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

**NOTE 4:**

```
sudo dnf install xterm
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-server-utils
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-apps
sudo dnf groupinstall "legacy-x"
```

Comment: Can you test with `sudo xterm`, to see if it's working ?

Comment: @Philippe I installed then I test, but Fails again with sudo. Please, CHECK the NOTE in my post.

Comment: If xterm is not working either, the problem may not be related to your java program. Now try to make xterm work with sudo, which is much simpler than trouibleshooting the whole java program.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ME WORKS (Not using root user!)

**`xhost +`**

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"
OS:linux
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:132)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel.isSupportedLookAndFeel(GTKLookAndFeel.java:1554)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:524)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:583)
    at org.bz.filefinder.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:87)
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

Now with `xhost +` works!

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"
OS:linux
JFrame.class.isAssignableFrom(RecursiveFolderAndFiles.class):true
RecursiveFolderAndFiles.class.isAssignableFrom(OneSearch.class):false
RulerPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(OneSearch.class):false
RulerPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(JPanel.class):false
JPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(RulerPanel.class):true
Jul 06, 2020 3:59:23 AM org.bz.filefinder.RecursiveFolderAndFiles <init>
INFO: System.getProperty("user.dir"): /home/joseluisbz
Jul 06, 2020 3:59:23 AM org.bz.filefinder.RecursiveFolderAndFiles <init>
INFO: System.getProperty("user.home"): /root
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

Now with `xhost -` fails!

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ xhost -
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo java -jar "/home/joseluisbz/Documents/FlexibleFileFinder-Full/dist/FlexibleFileFinder.jar"
OS:linux
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:132)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel.isSupportedLookAndFeel(GTKLookAndFeel.java:1554)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:524)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:583)
    at org.bz.filefinder.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:87)
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

**`dnf provides */xhost`**

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ dnf provides */xhost
Last metadata expiration check: 1:54:28 ago on Mon 06 Jul 2020 02:39:25 AM -05.
bash-completion-1:2.7-5.el8.noarch : Programmable completion for Bash
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xhost

bash-completion-1:2.7-5.el8.noarch : Programmable completion for Bash
Repo        : BaseOS
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/xhost

xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-27.el8.x86_64 : X.Org X11 X server utilities
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/xhost

xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-27.el8.x86_64 : X.Org X11 X server utilities
Repo        : AppStream
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/xhost

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

**`dnf info xorg-x11-server-utils`**

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ dnf info xorg-x11-server-utils
Last metadata expiration check: 2:00:45 ago on Mon 06 Jul 2020 02:39:25 AM -05.
Installed Packages
Name         : xorg-x11-server-utils
Version      : 7.7
Release      : 27.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 491 k
Source       : xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-27.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : AppStream
Summary      : X.Org X11 X server utilities
URL          : http://www.x.org
License      : MIT
Description  : A collection of utilities used to tweak and query the runtime configuration of
             : the X server.

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```